# React Native - I cannot send any FormData with fetch

Tags: javascript, android, image, react-native, expo

I was trying to send an image and some description from my React Native app to a Node Rest Api but it never reaches the api.
This is my code:

```
let formData = new FormData();

formData.append("imageFile", {
    uri: image.uri,
    type: "image/jpeg",
    name: filename,
});
/*
    image.uri is similar to this: "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData
    /%2540anonymous%252FAppTest_v1-7f36da10-9f18-4a65-97f6-55d9c75f3998/ImagePicker/
    e54acf1b-5391-4db3-87e5-a8765decf3c5.jpg",
    and filename: "e54acf1b-5391-4db3-87e5-a8765decf3c5.jpg"
*/

formData.append("data", {fromApp: "true", userId: "testID123"});

//console.log(formData);
try{
    const response = await fetch(
        serverIp + "/manageFiles/almacenImagenes",{
            method: "POST",
            //headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}, //doesn't work with or without this
            body: formData
        }
    );
    console.log("RESPONSE:",response);
    const resData = await response.json();
    console.log("resDATA:",resData);

}catch(err){
    console.log("ERROR:", err);
}
```

When I send an image, fetch throws the error: *[TypeError: Network request failed]*. And no request is received by my node server.
I've tried sending a FormData only with strings, something like:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("something","abc123");
```

That is sent, but the **body** of the request is empty.

I also prove this:

```
const response = await fetch(serverIp + "/login", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        fromApp: true,
        email,
        password
    })
});
```

And it works correctly, but with that I cannot send an image.

I'm using Expo *version 35.0.0* and React Native *version 0.59.8*, and I'm testing the app in a real *Android device*.
Please someone can tell what I'm doing wrong, I've been looking for an answer everywhere but I haven't found anything that works for me.

---

**Solution:**
I have solutioned this sending the image encoded in base64, and then decoding it in my Node server.

Comment: If you want to send an actual image, you need to turn it into a blob. If you want to send a stringified version of the body or the FormData, actually do so. Appending objects to the Formdata turns them into `[object Object]`, which is the default `.toString()` . But that still does not fully explain the network issue though.

Comment: I also tried using JSON.stringify() with the object or sending just an string, but the body received was empty. Moreover, Isn't that the way that images are sent in React Native?

Comment: Use an object is an example here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/v0.59.8/Libraries/Network/FormData.js#L65